# jQuery / AJAX - How to post data / login to a web site via XMLHTTPRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need some help. I'd like login to www.mywebsite.com/login.html and keep the cookies in order to be used when I submit the travel form because you need to login first before you can submit the form.

Nothing is happening when I try to click on "Login" button.

Below is my code and the screenshot of the form.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.post("https://www.mywebsite.com/login.html",
        {
          login: "alice007@gmail.com",
          password: "alice1995"
        },
        function(data,status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Send an HTTP POST request to a page and get the result back</button>

</body>
</html>
```

[screenshot of Login Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tzrI.png)

Comment: You need PHP to set cookies and session for logging in.

Comment: @Oen44 raises a good question. How are you setting the cookies?

Answer (score 0):

The code itself seems to be correct (click event is created), but some sites block these requests and throw "Cross-origin request blocked".

That will occur if you call this from www.mywebsite1.com/test.html to www.mywebsite2.com

I have tried for multiple sites including for www.google.com:

```
$.post("http://www.google.com",
```

See this image for more details what happened after button click: [image: Firefox - Developer Tools]

If you wish to enable CORS, you have to do that on the target server: https://enable-cors.org - but, for some admins it will be a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

Before I talk about the answer, it's important to know that the form button must have an ID. This is helpful later when you're trying to target that element. Here's an example

```
<button id="SendMyStatus">
  Send an HTTP POST request to a page and get the result back
</button>
$("button").click(function(){ ... }
```

or you can use `onClick` event of button.

```
<button onClick="SendMyStatus()"></button>

<script> function SendMyStatus(){ ... }</script>
```

Comment: @Garrett kadillak thank for edit words. I guess, I dont know enought  English